# Binary tree giving "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'"

Tags: python-3.x, binary-tree

I' trying to implement a method to a binary tree that give me the total sum of all the elements of the tree:

def totalsumprint(self):
print("The tree's value's total sum:")
self.totalsum(self.root)

```
def totalsum(self, node):
    if node:
        return node.value + self.totalsum(node.left) + self.totalsum(node.right)
```

This is what I currently have, but its giving me this error "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'", can someone help me figuring this up? Thank

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Is that the extent of your function or is that just a minor part of it?  Reason is,  ```if node is None```, you have no condition catching this and ergo, you return None.   even if (say) ```node.left``` is ```None```, then you have ```node.value + None...```  which is what your issue is.

Comment: Thank you! Yes that was the problem, but just adding the "else" return 0 was enough to solve it :)

Answer (score 0):

#### Try ensuring the function returns a zero, rather than `None`, if `node` is `None`

```
def totalsum(self, node):
    if node:
        return node.value + self.totalsum(node.left) + self.totalsum(node.right)
    else:
        return 0
```

Comment: Yes thank you, that was the problem, once it reached the bottom of the tree as it was None it returned a NoneType error.

Comment: Remember to mark the answer as correct. 8-)